# how to write a json file with php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have 4 input, which sent by Ajax 4 data, to a php file:
how can I load json file and then add new data whih php?

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="text" id="surname">
<input type="text" id="mobile">
<input type="text" id="email">
<script>
var name = $("#name").val();
var surname = $("#surname").val();
var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
$.ajax({type:"POST",
    url:"wjson.php",
    data:"name="+nombre+"&surname="+surname+"&mobile="+mobile+"&email="+email,
    success:function(data) {

    }
});
```

JSON file: (people.json)

```
{
    "1":
    {
        "Name" : "Jhon",
        "Surname" : "Kenneth",
        "mobile" : 329129293,
        "email" : "jhon@gmail.com"
    },
    "2":
    {
        "Name" : "Thor",
        "Surname" : "zvalk",
        "mobile" : 349229293,
        "email" : "thor@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

wjson.php file :

```
<?php
$nane = $_POST['name'];
$surname =$_POST['surname'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$email =$_POST['email'];
$str_datos = file_get_contents("people.json")
//add new data to people.json
?>
```

by the way people.json file is in my server

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
// Loading existing data:
$json = file_get_contents("people.json");
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// Adding new data:
$data[3] = array('Name' => 'Foo', 'Surname' => 'Bar');

// Writing modified data:
file_put_contents('people.json', json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```

However, reading and writing a blob of possibly large size just to add a small item or two is not the best idea. If your dataset starts growing, consider alternative solutions.